German Movie about a dad who has to look after his estranged daughter
I remember watching a movie in my German lesson where a man who has broken up with his girlfriend, who he has a kid with, has to look after the kid when the mom goes out of town. He is broke and his daughter accidentally burns down the house trying to make dinner.
Stuck for money, he is forced to turn to the daughter's step dad, a dentist,  for money and they become really good friends. In the end, the mom comes back and leaves her current husband for the protagonist.
As stated before, the film is in German, released mid-2000s and in colour. That's all I can remember so I hope it helps. 

Steven, is that you?

@BlueMoon93 Of course! Have you ever seen any of my work? I'm quite proud of them.

Is it Kokowääh (2011)?
To quote the Wikipedia page (translated poorly into English):

Ever since the moderately successful screenwriter Henry separated from his friend Katharina, he is at a personal and creative low point. The only thing he does is the screenplay of the television series "The forester of the Spreewald", which is ultimately sold out for lack of viewing. When his unexpected offer of working on the adaptation of the best-selling novel "Freiflug" is offered to him, his agent is finally able to change his life fundamentally. However, the author, with whom he is to work out the screenplay, is his ex-girlfriend Katharina.
When the eight-year-old Magdalena emerges, his life is finally out of line. In a letter that the little girl has with her, Magdalena is Henry's biological daughter. Until her mother Charlotte returns from a court of New York, Magdalena is to live with Henry. He has no idea how to deal with children, and wants to bring Magdalena back to her father Tristan. However, he refuses to take Magdalena back, because he has to overcome the shock, not her biological father, and his marriage to Charlotte is therefore on the sidelines.
Tristan also asks Henry to take responsibility for his daughter. Henry is overwhelmed with the whole situation. He tries to explain to Magdalena that he is her father. While working on the screenplay he again develops feelings for Katharina and also his relationship with Magdalena becomes more intense. However, he does not bring himself to tell Katharina of Magdalena, since she was begotten while he was still with Katharina. When the suspicious Katharina visits him at home, she meets Magdalena and learns the truth from her. Disappointed and injured by Henry's behavior, she leaves him and ends his professional co-operation with him.
To all this, Tristan suddenly asks his daughter back. Henry is painfully aware of how much Magdalena means to him. There is a conflict between the two men. He tries to express his feelings with a script, which he calls "Kokowääh". He sends Katharina to understand how he feels. After reading the screenplay, she meets Henry and reconciles with him. Together, they continue to work on the screenplay.
Charlotte has now returned from New York. It concludes a compromise to keep Magdalena both fathers.

Tristan is a dentist and Magdalena burns down the apartment, trying to make coq au vin.
Is this it?

Yes that's it! Thanks so much!
